# How can I write a getter for a class field whose dynamic type is different from declared type?

Tags: java, inheritance, getter

I have encountered a following situation at work, and I am looking for a better solution. There is a `BaseClass`, and one of its fields is declared to be of type `FieldBaseClass`. The field gets instantiated in child classes and has a dynamic type `FieldChildClass` then. I want to write a getter for the field that returns an instance of child class (`FieldChildClass`) and not of the parent. How can I achieve it without having to do a type cast?

I have tried putting getter into child class and casting return type to specific child class, but this seems ugly.

**BaseClass.java**

```java
public class BaseClass {

   protected FieldBaseClass field;

   public BaseClass() {
      field = calculateFieldValue();
   }

   public static class FieldBaseClass {
       protected String bar = "bar";
   }
}
```

**ChildClass.java**

```java
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

   public FieldChildClass calculateFieldValue() {
       return new FieldChildClass("foo");
   }


   public static class FieldChildClass extends FieldBaseClass {
      private String foo;

      public FieldChildClass(String foo) {
         this.foo = foo;
      }
   }

   public FieldChildClass getField() {
      return (FieldChildClass) field;
   }
}
```

Comment: There is logical mistake. If you are new to java or programming then look what an abstract class does. Can you tell me in what situations do you store the instance of a class in the same class. (One example would be enough).

Comment: @KhanSaab A singleton

Comment: @j.seashell A singleton does not need any hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) e.g. `T` to define the type of the field.

```
public class BaseClass<T extends FieldBaseClass> {
  protected T field;

  public T getField() {
    return field;
  } 
}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass<FieldChildClass> {

}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
FieldChildClass f = c.getField();
```

Comment: I think that's what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible. Basically when the field has declared type all You can do is try to hide it as described for example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Object_Oriented_Design/0330__Java_Inheritance_Hiding.htm). But I am not sure if this will suit Your needs.

I don't think You can do this otherwise without type casting.